# Is there a way to shorten jQuery code, especially when using show and hide functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find jQuery functions that might make this jQuery code shorter. I tried looking at toggle, but i couldn't see how it could work. I'm just trying to learn jQuery's best practices at the moment. Thank you.

```
$(".play").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  video.ref.playVideo();
  $(".play").hide();
  $(".pause").show();
});
$(".pause").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  video.ref.pauseVideo();
  $.(".pause").hide();
  $(".play").show();
});
```

Comment: Aside from not caching the selector results, that code is already pretty short.  You feel the need to make a succinct, 4-line method shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of how to make it shorter, but it can perform better by caching the two main jQuery objects and referring to the current object $(this) when possible.
`var $_play = $('#play'),
    $_pause = $('#pause');
$_play.click(function(e){
    video.ref.playVideo();
    $(this).hide();
    $_pause.show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$_pause.click(function(e){
    video.ref.pauseVideo();
    $(this).hide();
    $_play.show();
    e.preventDefault();
});`

Answer (score 0):

The code is short already, but you could combine the 2 events if you *really* wanted to.

```
var $playPause = $(".play,.pause").click(function(e){
    var func = $(this).hasClass('play') ? 'play' : 'pause';
    e.preventDefault();
    video.ref[func+'Video']();
    $playPause.toggle();
});
```